# Uploading Images to backblaze through API using python

Tags: python, image, api, non-ascii-characters

I have been trying to upload files to backblaze through API using python.

The following is the code snippet I used.

```
import json
import urllib2
import hashlib

upload_url = "" # Provided by b2_get_upload_url
upload_authorization_token = "" # Provided by b2_get_upload_url
file_data = "Now, I am become Death, the destroyer of worlds."
file_name = "oppenheimer_says.txt"
content_type = "text/plain"
sha1_of_file_data = hashlib.sha1(file_data).hexdigest()

headers = {
    'Authorization' : upload_authorization_token,
    'X-Bz-File-Name' :  file_name,
    'Content-Type' : content_type,
    'X-Bz-Content-Sha1' : sha1_of_file_data
}
request = urllib2.Request(upload_url, file_data, headers)

response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
response_data = json.loads(response.read())
response.close()
```

It works fine and am able to access file through web UI.

But when i tried to upload an image by modifying the code as given below(All other parts are same as above code)

```
with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as content_file:
    file_data = content_file.read()
file_name = "test.jpg"
content_type = "b2/x-auto"
```

it raises an error as given below

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 848, in _send_output
msg += message_body
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0:      ordinal not in range(128)
```

It worked fine when i base64 encoded the image content but the image is not accessible through the public link. Is there any other method to overcome this ?

Comment: try using the codecs library.  `import codecs`, then change `with open('test.jpg', 'rb') as..` to `with codecs.open('test.jpg', 'rb', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: @n1c9  When i tried it got another error as `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this by using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/),

`response = requests.post(upload_url, headers=headers, data=file_data)`